# No rule to make target (make project in different directories)

Tags: makefile

Excuse me for asking simple questions, but I can't find where the problem is.
I have an `src` directory, contains makefile and `obj` folder. An `include` folder and a `lib` one. The codes have provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nyognsd1ne5ca4/makefile.zip?dl=0).

```
IDIR =../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~
```

it gives me the following error:

```
gcc -c -o obj/hellomake.o hellomake.c -I../include
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/hellofunc.o', needed by 'hellomake'.  Stop.
```

It uses the same rule for creating `.o` files and hellomake file. but the last one does not work.
Thanks for any comment or guide.

Comment: The example comes from here: (http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

Comment: If your makefile is in `src`, and you run it in `src`, then there is
no file called `hellofunc.c` in `src`. Have you misspelled it
(`hellofun.c`)?

Comment: `hellomake.c` is in `src` and `hellofunc.c` is in `lib`. Could you please take a look at files? it's just a few ones.

Comment: So as I said, *there is no file called* `hellofunc.c` *in* `src`. It is
in `lib`. (Why?) Your makefile, when run in `src`, needs a
file called `hellofunc.c` *in that directory*, to match your
rule: `$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)`

Comment: Thank you Mike, I moved the makefunc.c to src. 
It worked. But is there any way to use some files in `../lib` and in `src` folder only be the main file (`hellomake.c`)?

Comment: Thank you anyway. Maybe this is not common to put function files outside the `src` directory.

Comment: A `src` folder in a project that is conventionally where you
put source files (`*.c`,`*.cpp`,..). A `lib` folder is conventionaally
a place for compiled libraries (`*.a`,`*.so`). `make` does not care how you organize
your files in directories, but your makefile has to tell `make` the truth about
how they are organized. If you want to know how you can organize groups
of source files in different directories for `make`, read about [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)
in the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `src` directory, but you don't tell Make about it. Make is complaining that there is no `hellofunc.c`. (There is a`src/hellofunc.c`, but Make didn't know to look there.) Try this:

```
SRC := src

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: excuse me I still have the same error. makefile is in src directory.

Comment: @Abolfazl: Where do you execute Make?